# How to create windows context menu and overlay icons in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I am new to C#, I am struggling to find a useful article on how to add windows context menu and overlay icons to folders programmatically using C#. In some articles, I figured out that, by using shell extensions, I can do this? Can any one explain me what are these shell extensions and any useful tutorial for beginners on implementing the context menu, overlay icons using c#. Please suggest any useful book to know about these shell extensions.